# Designing 1 on 1 battle: improving on Pokemon's model

Tags: game-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Designing AI in a 1 on 1 battle similar to Pokemon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28750/designing-ai-in-a-1-on-1-battle-similar-to-pokemon)

I am developing an android game that uses a similar battle style to Pokemon.  Essentially you are going 1 on 1 against an opponent and you select from 4 moves to bring their health to 0.  I also will be implement items such as healing potions, antidotes etc.

My problem/question deals with how I can improve upon the simple battle system that Pokemon has.  What suggestions or ideas do you have that would improve gameplay and avoid everything becoming repetitive?

I've already come up with a couple ideas that I would like some feedback on.

1. Speed system - In pokemon, the speed stat for the most part only determines which pokemon attacks first.  I would like to implement as system where each monster has a speed stat that determines how often it can go and the monster with the lowest speedVariable goes next..  THe speed stat would be an arbitrary unit 1-100 that is added to the monsters speedVariable every time it makes an attack.  Also attacks have their own speed stat that gets added so high damage attacks add more time between attacks to provide balance.

FOr example: Monster A - 50 base speed, Monster B - 30 base speed
"Turn" one - B has lower speed so subtract difference and B gets to choose a move 
           A(20) B(0)   - uses an attack that has a speed of 70. (0 + 70 + 30) = 100;
"Turn" two - A(20) B(100) figure out which goes next and adjust speedVariable
           A(0)B(80) - A uses a weaker attack with a speed of 25. (0+25+50) = 80
           A(75)B(80) - A would get to go again.

2. I also thought using statuses/debuffs to augment moves would be a nice addition.  If you use a fire attack on a monster it becomes burned for a certain number of turns.  Certain moves do extra damage (25-50%) when a monster has the burned status.  I also thought freezing/slowing with ice spells would increase a monsters speedVariable.

Comment: These two things you mentioned already exists in pokemon's battles.

Comment: @NemoStein in which games?

Comment: @willmer welcome to the site! This question is quite open-ended and has no "right answer" per se, so it will likely be closed as such. But you're on the right track, it looks like.

Comment: @ashes999 Sorry, I've been using stackoverload where all the questions are clearly geared to having one answer such as fixing code errors.  It seems like game development is more open ended by nature.  Would there be a better place for me to seek advice/criticism on this?

Comment: @NemoStein I am aware that the statuses are in pokemon battles but they only go so far as to cause the pokemon to be unable to use a move (sleep/paralyze), miss more often, change attack/defenses, and suffer damage over time (burn, poison).  I'm looking to add something a little more than just damage over time effects.

Comment: @willmer I hope your question doesn't get closed personally, but I don't see it as a good fit to the style of this site (check the FAQ). You can try game development forums, or the site chat (albeit you don't have enough rep for chat).

Comment: I closed this question since it seems like you meant to edit this question instead of posting the linked duplicate.  Let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: @Tetrad, I didn't want to overload one question so I made two since the other "duplicate" deals with AI in battle rather than the design of my battle.  I will take my question to the forums then.  I'm obviously new here and should have read the FAQ first. Sorry.

Comment: This was not an exact duplicate. This question was about how the mechanics of the battle should work. The question it has been closed as an exact duplicate of is asking about how to make a pokemon AI. These questions are completely different. This question is, however, not constructive, since it would call for extended discussion and opinions.

Comment: Even if I think the question is a bit too broad for the scope of the site, I think that a good suggestion could be to explore other turn-based RPGs, even if they look far from the standard "pokemon clone" game. Your suggestion on the speed stat reminds me of the speed system of Final Fantasy X, that I appreciated, maybe it is worth to give a look.